# Understanding The Proper Usage of "Contingency Fee Basis" vs. "Contingent Fee Basis"

Tags: legalese

I am writing for an law firm and am trying to understand what is the appropriate usage of "contingent fee basis" versus "contingency fee basis."

I have always used the term "Contingency Fee Basis" when referring to the type of fee collection that attorneys use for personal injury cases. Is there a difference between contingent and contingency, or is it a matter of style?

Comment: The fee is based on the contingency of winning the case.  No win, no fee to pay.  Why are considering changing the term at this point?  I would not adjust terms of art, because specialized vocabulary is taken exactly as is.

Comment: I parse the two differently.  “Contingency Fee Basis” is the basis for a contingency fee, while “Contingent fee basis” would be a fee basis that is contingent on something.

Comment: @Jim that makes sense to me. I will use that as a guide moving forward. Thank you!